# Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential -python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I get this problem when I run my code (It uploads files to google drive folder, then return the shareable link of the files uploaded):

```
import json
import requests
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly"]
def authenticate_google_drive():
    # Set your credentials (client ID and secret) obtaned from the Google API Console
    client_id = "ClientXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    client_secret = "XXXXXXX"
    refresh_token = "XXXXX"  

    # Refresh the access token
    refresh_token_url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
    payload = {
        'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
        'client_id': client_id,
        'client_secret': client_secret,
        'refresh_token': refresh_token
    }
    response = requests.post(refresh_token_url, data=payload)
    access_token = json.loads(response.text).get('refresh_token')
    return access_token

def upload_file_to_google_drive(file_path, folder_id):
    access_token = authenticate_google_drive()

    # Prepare metadata for the file
    metadata = {
        'name': 'my_uploaded_file.jpg',
        'parents': [folder_id]
    }

    # Prepare the file data
    files = {
        'data': ('metadata', json.dumps(metadata), 'application/json'),
        'file': open(file_path, 'rb').read()
    }

    # Upload the file to Google Drive
    response = requests.post(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart',
        headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'},
        files=files
    )

    if response.status_code == 200:
        file_id = json.loads(response.text).get('id')
        shareable_link = f'https://drive.google.com/file/d/{file_id}/view'
        print(f'Shareable link for my_uploaded_file.jpg: {shareable_link}')
    else:
     print (response.text)
     print('Error uploading the file to Google Drive.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_path = "N:\Berry store\Database\\0076.jpg"
    folder_id = '1ugqo3jmMJGXipk8Eq4TdEnrqp_xa5GUY'
    upload_file_to_google_drive(file_path, folder_id)
```

I tried to create a new project on google cloud console, tried to replace access token with refresh token.
but it always gives me this error.
it ran properly for the first time then stopped working.

Comment: 1) An OAuth Refresh Token is not the same as an OAuth Access Token. Refresh tokens are used to request an Access token. 2) Your code that directly manages OAuth tokens will not work long-term because refresh tokens expire and can be invalidated at any time. Implement Google's normal OAuth flow for user accounts (which requires using a web browser) or switch to a service account.